# ElasticSearch Adding field in JSON before indexing

Tags: java, json, elasticsearch

[This is my first post, please excuse me if I'm doing something wrong! (also sorry for my bad English)]

I'm try to develop a Mapper/Plugin for elasticsearch (in Java) that analyze some specified fields of JSON and add another field with the result of the analysis before storing and indexing the data.

EG:
I start with this popular JSON:

```
{
    "tweet" {
        "user" : "kimchy",
        "message" : "This is a tweet!",
        "postDate" : "2009-11-15T14:12:12",
        "priority" : 4,
        "rank" : 12.3
    }
}
```

And, before the indexing, I Want it like:

```
{
    "tweet" {
        "user" : "kimchy",
        "message" : "This is a tweet!",
        "postDate" : "2009-11-15T14:12:12",
        "priority" : 4,
        "rank" : 12.3
        "IsKimchy" : "Yes"
    }
}
```

Here I suppose to read the field "user" and if the user is Kimchy I create another field that contain "Yes".
how can I analyze a field (using java) like this before the indexing?

As I know I can copy the content of a field in an other using Copy_to, so I can work only on a field, maybe it can help?

Comment: http://www.elasticsearch.org/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/mapping-transform.html

Comment: Thanks a lot Kostantintin V. Salikohov for your hint, it's helpfull, but I want to do the analysis in java before indexing the data! I had a java lib (made years ago) and I want simply implement this functionalisty in the analysis of elaticsearch fields.
Thanks to you I can duplicate and prepare the other field!

Answer (score 0):

I had finally found a solution for my problem, I'll post it here, hope to help someone else!

the best solution for me (in Terms of Speed and integration) was a Custom mapper!

I had use this demo code https://github.com/dadoonet/elasticsearch-mapper-demo to implement my mapper class that analyze the Json Faster than scripting and add a custom field in record!

Cheers!